# rewriting "/foo/bar" to "index.html" adds "foo" to all relative urls

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite all incoming urls (that don't link to a physical file on the filesystem) to my index.html (and process the urls with history.js in there further)

### my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite everything that isn't a real file to index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ www.xy.de/index.html
```

`localhost/www.xy.de/<foo>` works perfectly, but

`localhost/www.xy.de/<foo>/<bar>` not really. Even in the second example, it gets redirected to the index.html, but something strange happens:

### rewrite.log:

http://sprunge.us/GiEM (same as below for better reading)

```
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] add path info postfix: /srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc -> /srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc/z
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc/z -> yxc/z
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'yxc/z'
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (4) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] RewriteCond: input='/srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc' pattern='!-f' => matched
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (4) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] RewriteCond: input='/srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc' pattern='!-d' => matched
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (2) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] rewrite 'yxc/z' -> 'www.xy.de/index.html'
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] add per-dir prefix: www.xy.de/index.html -> /srv/http/www.xy.de/www.xy.de/index.html
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (2) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] trying to replace prefix /srv/http/www.xy.de/ with /
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /srv/http/www.xy.de/www.xy.de/index.html -> www.xy.de/index.html
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (4) add subst prefix: www.xy.de/index.html -> /www.xy.de/index.html
[...][rid#1dfc7e0/initial] (1) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] internal redirect with /www.xy.de/index.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[...][rid#1e08850/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/http/www.xy.de/index.html -> index.html
[...][rid#1e08850/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'index.html'
[...][rid#1e08850/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] RewriteCond: input='/srv/http/www.xy.de/index.html' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[...][rid#1e08850/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] pass through /srv/http/www.xy.de/index.html
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] add path info postfix: /srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc -> /srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc/static/main.css
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc/static/main.css -> yxc/static/main.css
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'yxc/static/main.css'
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (4) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] RewriteCond: input='/srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc' pattern='!-f' => matched
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (4) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] RewriteCond: input='/srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc' pattern='!-d' => matched
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (2) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] rewrite 'yxc/static/main.css' -> 'www.xy.de/index.html'
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (3) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] add per-dir prefix: www.xy.de/index.html -> /srv/http/www.xy.de/www.xy.de/index.html
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (2) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] trying to replace prefix /srv/http/www.xy.de/ with /
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /srv/http/www.xy.de/www.xy.de/index.html -> www.xy.de/index.html
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (4) add subst prefix: www.xy.de/index.html -> /www.xy.de/index.html
[...][rid#1e00800/initial] (1) [perdir /srv/http/www.xy.de/] internal redirect with /www.xy.de/index.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

The problem lies in this line:

`add path info postfix: /srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc -> /srv/http/www.xy.de/yxc/static/main.css`
This happens for all the images/scripts/stylesheets (so all relative links) in the html file and of course since there is no file with this prefix, everything gets redirected to index.html and everything is messed up.

**Why does the webserver add the `yxc` to the path? And how can i prevent this behaviour?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the webserver add the yxc to the path? And how can i prevent this behaviour?

This is how relative links work. The browser tries to determine what the URI base is using the URI of the request. So when the browser requests `http://localhost/ww.xy.de/yxc/z`, the URI is `/www.xy.de/yxc/z` and the BASE is `/www.xy.de/yxc/`. With this base, **all relative links will have this appended to the front of the link**.

You need to either change all your links to absolute links, or add a

```
<base href="/www.xy.de/">
```

to the header of your index.html page.